# How to solve this htaccess redirect error

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(views|css|js|media|partials|php)
RewriteRule (.*) /views/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The last two lines (to force SSL) gives the following error: `Load cannot follow more than 20 redirections`. This apparently get caused by a page redirecting to another page, who is redirecting to the first page, creating a loop.

However, I don't see how this `.htaccess` is causing that.

Comment: What is `{THE_REQUEST}` ?

Comment: @Anonymous I don't know

Answer (score 0):

if you are just writing .htaccess for force SSL then use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```